# Spark Java - Collect multiple columns into array column

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I have a dataframe with multiple columns:

```
| a | b | c | d |
-----------------
| 0 | 4 | 3 | 6 |
| 1 | 7 | 0 | 4 |
| 2 | 4 | 3 | 6 |
| 3 | 9 | 5 | 9 |
```

I would now like to combine `[b,c,d]` into a single column. However, *I do not know, how big the list of columns will be*, otherwise I could just use a UDF3 to combine the three.

So the desired outcome is:

```
| a | combined  |
-----------------
| 0 | [4, 3, 6] |
| 1 | [7, 0, 4] |
| 2 | [4, 3, 6] |
| 3 | [9, 5, 9] |
```

How can I achieve this?

Non-working pseudo-code:

```
public static Dataset<Row> mergeColumns(Dataset<Row> ds, List<String> columns) {
   return ds.withColumn("combined", collectAsList(columns))
}
```

Worst-case workaround would be a switch statement on the number of input columns and then write a UDF each for, i.e. 2-20 input columns and throw an error, if more input columns are supplied.

Comment: use array inbuilt function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Ramesh mentioned in his comment, you can use `array` function. You only need to convert your columns list to `Column` array.

```
public static Dataset<Row> mergeColumns(Dataset<Row> ds, List<String> columns) {
    return ds.withColumn("combined", functions.array(columns.stream().map(functions::col).toArray(Column[]::new)))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val newDF = df.drop("a")

//create a new dataframe to get the combination of columns except the first column
val df2 = df.withColumn("combined", concat_ws(",",newDF.columns.map(collist => 
col(collist)): _*))

//new dataframe to select only the first and combined columns
val columnNames = Seq("a", "combined")
df2.select(columnNames.head, columnNames.tail:_*).show()
```

Comment: That would result in a column of StringType, rather than an array, or?